# Ruby, how to sort objects based on obect's hash table value?

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array of objects with a hash that has a value.  I want to sort all the objects based on that hash value.  I tried `objs.sort_by {|obj| obj.hash["date"]}` but that did not work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You're not sharing nearly enough. What are the objects? How do you retrieve the value? What do you mean by "did not work"? What is the expected output? Did you get an error message?

Comment: Is `obj.has["date"]` actually a date object or a date in string form or something else? Please be specific.

Comment: As well as clarifying the question, please add an example. Whenever you provide an example (generally a good thing), 1) make it as simple as possible; 2) show the desired result and 3) attach a variable to all input objects (e.g, `arr = [1,2,3]`), so that readers can refer to those variables (e.g., `arr`) in answers and comments without having to define them.

Comment: "did not work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`sort_by` always works, if you aren't getting the results you want then you aren't giving it the correct information. If you want it to sort by Dates and you are passing a string it will sort the string alphabetically. You need to make sure that whatever `obj.hash['date']` is the correct type, as in DateTime, Date, Integer, and so on.

In your case, you probably need to use `sort` the documentation is here https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort.

Assuming you want to sort by Date and it is a string you could do

```
objs.sort { |a, b| DateTime.parse(b.hash['date']) <=> DateTime.parse(a.hash['date']) }
```

If you wanted to use `sort_by` you could do

```
objs.sort { |obj| DateTime.parse(obj.hash['date']) }
```

As the link above states, `sort` is faster than `sort_by` and gives you more control. I would recommend reading the entire sort section.

Here is a link to `DateTime.parse` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse. I don't know your format but it is easy to parse any format with `DateTime.strptime` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime.

I hope that helps if you want to give me more information I can see if I can give you a better answer.

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem.  I was sorting the actual dates alphabetically and not using DateTime.